# Javascript removing an object from a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

I am creating a game in which I have an array of objects, one of the arrays holds all the missile objects. This array is needing to have missiles removed from it frequently as they hit walls (or players) but I cant seem to find a way to remove the object from the array without getting messy code. Preferably I would want a way that removes the object from within within one of the objects functions e.g `missiles.splice(this,1)`.

An example of the piece of code is as follows

```
Missiles.prototype.Draw = function () {
    if (this.x >= -200) {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.fillStyle = "Black";
        ctx.rect(this.x,this.y,this.width,this.height);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.fill();
    } else {
        missileCount.splice(this,1);
        console.log('removed a missile')
    }
};
```

But, when I use this I have random missiles on the screen disappearing

I have a pastebin with my code in it (use the following link it may help)
http://pastebin.com/f5S8zhJg

The Game map is infinite in size which is quite interesting.

Comment: Did you check the `splice` method?

Comment: That is what i use in my code, the specific line is missileCount.splice(this,1); is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Check the documentation to be 100% sure.

Comment: The problem is i still get missiles randomly disappearing from the screen also when I refer to 'this' i am refering to the object that is currently being executed is that okay?

Comment: `missileCount` is an array.  `splice` takes 2 ints.  `this` is an instance of `Missiles`.  Without wading through your code, I think you want `missleCount.splice(missleCount.indexOf(this),1)`

Comment: Please make sure that you are properly indexing the `splice`.

Comment: okay thank you @JohnGreen I will try :)

Comment: yeah that works, thanks! i realise now that the splice method requires an index reference rather than what is within that index

Comment: I suppose that was enough to constitute an answer... and have made one as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`missileCount` is an array.

`splice` takes 2 ints.

`this` is an instance of Missiles.

Without wading through your code, I think you want:

```
missleCount.splice(missleCount.indexOf(this),1);
```